# Fetch API Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fetch-api

I'm working on this API and for any reason it returns me the message Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

I'm doing MySQL-connection, in here everything is ok but, the problem appears when I try to do the POST request.
My MySQL database is working at 100%.

### CODE API

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

router.post("/postPersona", MiddlewareMultipart, (req, res, next) => {
    //console.log("." + req.files.Src.path.split("public")[1]);
    //console.log(req.body);

    var query = 'CALL addPersonas(?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    var imgPath = "." + req.files.Src.path.split("public")[1];

    var datos =
        [
            req.body.Nombre,
            req.body.Telefono,
            req.body.Curp,
            req.body.ECivil,
            Number(req.body.Edad),
            imgPath
        ]

    conn.query(query, datos, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error" + err);
            res.send(JSON.stringify("Error: " + err));
        }
        else {
            console.log(results);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
        }
    });
});
```

### FRONT END JS

```
var Agregar = () => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Nombre", NomSrc.value);
    formData.append("Telefono", TelSrc.value);
    formData.append("Curp", CurpSrc.value);
    formData.append("ECivil", EstCSrc);
    formData.append("Edad", EdadSrc.value);
    formData.append("Src", ImgSrc.files[0]);

    var url = "http://localhost:3000/apiMYSQL/postPersona";

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        })
}
```

### Console.log(result)

```
OkPacket { 
    fieldCount: 0, 
    affectedRows: 1,
     insertId: 0, 
     serverStatus: 2, 
     warningCount: 0, 
     message: '', 
     protocol41: true, 
     changedRows: 0 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Error: " + err is not a json object. It is not valid.

```
if (err) {
    console.log("Error" + err);
    //res.send(JSON.stringify("Error: " + err));
    res.send(JSON.stringify( {Error: err }));
}
```

And even simplier;

```
if (err) {
    console.log("Error" + err);
    //res.send(JSON.stringify("Error: " + err));
    //res.send(JSON.stringify( {Error: err }));
    res.json({Error: err });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `json` instead of `send`, so modify the following:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
```

to:

```
res.json({ results });
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: can you please post the console log for your `console.log(results);` and are you getting this error from the front end or backend?

Comment: OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }

Comment: The error comes when i try to upload the info from the frontend to backend

Comment: try changing it to `res.send({ results });` based on your `console.log(results);` log it is not an array but an object

Comment: The error has gone, but int the console log the object doesnt appears

Comment: you mean console.log(results) does not print anything and the data appear in the database normally?!

Comment: Yes!, So i dont know if the data needs to appear in the console.log()

Comment: yes it should normally show on your console.log(), but the error is resolved so that's a +